# How do I disable strict redirection when validation fails in Laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, redirect, laravel-7

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic):

> In the case of a traditional HTTP request, a redirect response will be generated, while a JSON response will be sent for AJAX requests.

In Laravel 7, when validation fails, it automatically redirects user back to the previous page. Only when request is AJAX-like, Laravel generates JSON-error.

So my question is how to absolutely disable redirection when validation fails in Laravel 7 regardless request type?

Comment: you can see this. perhaps it will be help you. :)
https://github.com/theanik/LaraAjax/blob/master/resources/views/customer/index.blade.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a manual validation, instead of using:

```
$request->validate()
```

you need to do it like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'value1' => 'required|max:255',
    'value2' => 'required',
]);

if ($validator->fails())          
    //Do whatever you want
}

//Continue normally if there are no validation errors
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to use validation without extra code. I need smth that solves my problem for all project at once.

Comment: What do you want to do instead? always return a json response?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I want validation to fail only with json.